# gzip command is not working in shell script

Tags: shell, script, crontab

If I run my script through crontab, gzip is not working fine. If I run the same script manually gzip is working.

The command we have in our script is

```
gzip -vf $path/file.eee
```

In my script I am generating one log file which is in `.exp` format, then I am trying to compress it by using gzip command

```
gzip -vf $PATH/file.exp
```

After this expecting `file.exp.gz` but gzip is failing, I saw the gzip status it is returning 141. Apart from gzip this script is working fine another commands are working fine.

`$PATH` is path to `file.exp`. I copied the `file.exp` to `/root` folder. In root folder I placed one test script which is having `gzip -vf /root/file.exp` command. This test script I added to crontab which is working fine. After completion of the crontab I saw the output in root folder their i could see `file.exp.gz` file. In crontab I gave proper user and command.

Comment: What means "not working fine"?

Comment: Your question is very low quality. I guess crontab is running in another folder, than if you run it manually.

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to SuperUser. Please read [How do I ask a good question ?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "Also, share with us your findings.  Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: try `gzip -vf $path/file.eee 1>~/testmsg.txt 2>~/testerr.txt` and read error messages from those files in user's home directory. Check if any other command is actually working "in crontab" like creating a directory. Make sure a user crontab is impersonating has required access rights.

Comment: Hi, in my script i am generating one log file which is in .exp format, then i am trying to compress it by using gzip command (gzip -vf $PATH/file.exp) after this expecting file.exp.gz but gzip is failing, i saw the gzip status it is returning 141. apart from gzip this script is working fine another commands are working fine

Comment: You really use `$PATH`/`$path`? It's system variable

Answer (score 1):

**Exit code:**

In exit values, a value above 128 indicates termination due to a signal, and the amount above 128 signifies which signal caused the termination. So, if we subtract 128 from the OP's exit code of 141, we get 13, which corresponds to SIGPIPE (`man 7 signal` for a list of standard signals and their corresponding integer values).

The man page lists SIGPIPE's comment as "Broken pipe: write to pipe with no readers".

**Variable:**

You really use `$PATH` / `$path`?

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
echo $path
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin
```

**About cron job:**

Cron jobs run on minimal envirnoment. `$PATH` is different in cron and shell session.

**Partial answer based on You informations:**

I guess, last entry in `$PATH` in Your shell session contains path to Your script. `file.exp` is created in this path.

Comment: Yes $PATH is path to file.exp . I copied the file.exp to /root folder. In root folder i placed one test script which is having gzip -vf /root/file.exp command. this test script i added to crontab which is working fine. after completion of the crontab i saw the output in root folder their i could see file.exp.gz file.In crontab i gave proper user and command

Comment: @damodar Try to use full path to `file.exp` instead of `$path/file.exp`